# Image Texturing - Using cycle's nodes to scale image texture and randomly rotate them

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, image

Is there a way to randomly rotate an image texture randomly and keep its mapping scalable? Im sure this has already been asked but can't seem to find it. If someone can redirect me to the appropriate thread/question that would be awesome.

If not here is the texture im trying to achieve:

[image]

I created a tiled image in illustrator and imported it into blender as an image texture. I have ran my nodes to get the image texture scalable but can't figure out how to randomly rotate it.

Here is what I have achieved:

[image]
[image]

This is what my current node setup looks like. The top part is for an added procedural texture to create more roughness outside of the image texture.

[image: Node setup]

Also here is the image texture I created in illustrator:

[image]

BLEND FILE:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Still trying to figure these nodes out and the math behind them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could append your blend file to [our upload facility](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).  I'm too lazy to recreate all those nodes ;)

Comment: @Merlin I uploaded the blend file for ya and everyone else! totally forgot to do that!

Comment: This question perhaps would have been harder to answer when it was asked.  I don't think vector rotate existed then, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just faced a similar issue, so I took a look at your file.  In the Tile-able image texture frame, you start with a *Mapping* node into a *Separate XYZ*.  I added the following nodes between them.

[image]

This all centers around the *Vector Rotate* node.  To explain, we start by taking the *Vector* output from your *Mapping* node into a *Voronoi Texture* with a *Scale* of 1.  We have to add another *Mapping* node in between to align the grid with the original output.

[image]

Now we can take the *Color* output and multiply it by some number and throw it into the *Angle* input of the *Vector Rotate* node, and we can take *Position* and put it into the *Center* input.  However, we must include yet another *Mapping* node in between to correct the transformation we made previously.  If we don't, the locations are all off.

[image]

This does introduce a slight issue.  The corners of the repeated image will show up as in the following image.

[image]

So you may have wondered what this mysterious noodle coming from the *Distance* output is.  I used this with a *Color Ramp* set to *Constant* to generate a mask that we can subtract out of your image and solve for these corners.

[image]

[image]

Your original *Mapping* node can be used as a control for x & Y Location, Z Rotation, and X & Y Scale.

[image]